# What happens when you slow charge a li-po?

Tags: battery-charging, low-power

Basically, what actually happens when you slow charge a li-po/li-ion battery? When I say slow, I mean C/50 or lower. Is there any place to get more detailed information regarding different (unusual) ways of charging batteries? I know you're supposed to do constant current then constant voltage, but is that just to minimise charging time, or does not doing that actually harm the battery?

I was looking at some chips like the LTC4070, and that seems to imply that charging them like that is ok? Also, what happens if you never really let it discharge, and basically keep it charged around 3.5V forever, sometimes drawing a few ma for a bit, sometimes charging a few ma for a bit?

Edit: Assuming you charge faster than the self discharge

Comment: If you charge slower than the self discharge you don't charge at all. But other than that... I mean, solar charging of battery banks works fine...

Answer (score 2):

With lithium chemistry, if you allow the voltage to exceed 4.2v, or stay at 4.2v for any length of time, you harm the cell.

This is why you have to have a limited voltage to finish charging. You must also stop charging once fully charged, to allow the voltage to drop back from 4.2v, and only give infrequent top-ups.

Even C/50 may exceed 4.2v on a fully charged cell.

Floating at a voltage << 4.2v, for instance the 3.5v you mention, should be OK for lifetime, but the usable capacity will be a long way short of 100%, so making poor use of the expensive chemistry you have just bought. However, if you have the cell, and don't need the runtime, then a low voltage float should work.

Comment: Thanks, when you say usable capacity, I assume you mean the normal capacity left in the battery at that voltage level. If, after doing this for a while, you then charged the battery up to its normal voltage (4V or 3.9V or whatever) would you see any loss of capacity? I guess what I'm asking is, does doing this have any permanent effect on the battery?

Comment: Unfortunately there's a dearth of information from the manufacturers about use of batteries in this mode. I had an application a few years ago, and received no advice from them other than regimes designed to maximise capacity and discharge rate. So you're on your own. If you avoid the known ways of accelerating their demise, overvoltage, undervoltage, overheating, then the hope is that you should be left with the standard 5 year or so wearout.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'll just try it and see. Maybe I can write a paper on my results then :P